# Excel filling permutations

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an algorithm that generates permutations, and am wondering how i can fill up an excel sheet to view these permutations.

For example, I want to present "XXOXXOOO" in excel cells, except I have a hundred or more so of these combinations. Right now, everything is of string type.

Comment: You want the output in one cell or one letter per cell and is it always 8 characters?

Comment: one letter per cell

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dynamic array formula `SEQUENCE`then put this in the first cell:

```
=IF(--MID(TEXT(DEC2BIN(SEQUENCE(2^8,,0)),"00000000"),SEQUENCE(,8),1)=1,"X","O")
```

And Excel will spill all the combinations.

[image]

---

If not then put this in the first cell:

```
=IF(--MID(TEXT(DEC2BIN(ROW($ZZ1)),"00000000"),COLUMN(A$1),1)=1,"X","O")
```

Copy over 8 columns and down 256 rows.

[image]